# How to place an image in node js api created on own from local folder

Tags: reactjs, node.js, import

I am creating an API for my project using Node Js. I want to place an image for each object in the array. The project is in react so I just import image from the folder like
`import { Thermite } from "./assets/operators/thermite.png"` but this doesnt work and I searched online but cant figure it out.
I want to upload an image and display it on the webpage when in the react app

API.JS

```
import { Thermite } from "./assets/operators/thermite.png"

const app = require("express")()
const cors = require("cors")
const PORT = 8000

app.use(cors({}))

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send({
    operators: [
      {
        img: Thermite,
        name: "Thermite",
        side: "Attack",
      },
      {
        name: "Ash",
        side: "Attack",
      },
      {
        name: "Vigil",
        side: "Defense",
      },
    ],
  })
})

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server running on ${PORT}`))
```

APP.JSX

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

function App() {
  let [operators, setOperators] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000")
      const data = await res.json()
      setOperators(data.operators)
    }
    fetchData()
  })

  return (
    <>
      {operators.map((op, idx) => {
        return (
          <div key={idx} className="flex flex-col">
            <div className="flex gap-4 px-4">
              <p>{op.img}</p>
              <p>{op.name}</p>
              <p>{op.side}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't import an image from NodeJS and send it with an API. Importing an image only works with builders like Webpack when you import the file inside your Front-End code. You have two options read the file and convert it to base64 or use the path to file from the API. In the second case, you need to expose the asset directory so the front end can read it.

Comment: You can either create an endpoint which will serve the static images with proper content type header and put the image url in the frontend inside the href attribute of the img tag, or simply you can convert the image into base64 and send it via the api and directly add the base64 file into the href attribute.

Comment: @DipeshShrestha this is what I've written. This is not a question. This is the answer.